# how can differentiate between zones and counties while searching for US states

Tags: timezone

I am developing a web app. I need to know difference between US zones and county.

I think one zone can have many counties but how exactly they divide zones and counties please explain I.e

```
state=   (Alabama)
 zone(code:name)=     ALZ041    :Autauga
county(code:name)=  ALC001: Autauga
```